# How to use variable globally in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have a vuejs project and want to use some variable (globally) in any of my components (Variable will not change its value).
I created a variable called `STEPS` in `somefile.js` and imported it from components where I want to use.

```
// somefile.js

export const STEPS = {
  PROJECT: 'project',
  USER: 'user',
  SUMMARY: 'summary',
}

// maybe freeze object here because value will not be changed
```

```
// component1.vue

import { STEPS } from 'somefile.js'

export default {
   methods: {
     someMethod(value) {
       if (value === STEPS.PROJECT) {
         // do something
       }
     }
   }
}
```

```
// component2.vue

import { STEPS } from 'somefile.js'

export default {
   methods: {
     someMethod(value) {
       if (value === STEPS.USER) {
         // do something
       }
     }
   }
}
```

So this actually works? I don't get any errors or anything. But I'm just wondering .. I am not sure if it's okay to use it like this? Just making a .js file and import it anywhere in your code and use it?

So..
I found 2 ways how people use global variables in vuejs.

1. using instance properties
   https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Base-Example

```
Vue.prototype.$STEPS = {
  PROJECT: 'project',
  USER: 'user',
  SUMMARY: 'summary',
}


created() {
   console.log(this.$STEPS)
}
```

2. Using mixins
   https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

```
var mixin = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: 'hello',
      foo: 'abc'
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  mixins: [mixin],
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: 'goodbye',
      bar: 'def'
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log(this.$data)
    // => { message: "goodbye", foo: "abc", bar: "def" }
  }
})
```

**So my question is is it okay to use how I used global variable? Just making a variable in javascript file and importing it..
Or should I change it to `using instance properties` or `mixins`?**

Comment: This is a correct way to do this for framework-independent globals. Vue 3 doesn't have instance properties that are accessible everywhere, so using mixins is not future-proof

Comment: What you are doing is perfectly fine, You can also do `.env` files https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables - This link is for vue cli but can work with webpack and other ways.

Comment: Yes this is perfectly fine. Only disadvantage of doing it like that is you can not access `STEPS` directly from the template...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the way you do it is totally fine. If you want to manage your data centrally where is can be accessed by all components (and can even be changed across all of them simultaneously), you could also have a look at [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGAu__J4xoc&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i371QO_Rtkl26MwtiJ30P2&index=1) is also a great (but maybe outdated) tutorial on Vuex.